# Передача DateTime c Zone Java

Tags: java, json, rest, datetime, timezone

Необходимо передавать DateTime c timezone в Response.

Как это сделано сейчас

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
private DateTime hiringDate;
```

Проблема в том, что данные необходимо передавать не в UTC, а с учетом timezone хранящейся в DateTime.
Необходимо задать в pattern формат который будет удовлетворять данному запросу. На просторах интернета ответа не нашлось.

Comment: то, что сейчас в pattern, вполне удовлетворяет данному запросу

Comment: @Эникейщик Проблема заключается в том что Z считается сокращением от ZULU и применяется для обозначения даты в формате UTC, а данные в этой переменной могут содержать все часовые пояса которые есть на территории РФ.  Передачу как есть в формате UTC прошу не предлагать)

Comment: я мало что понял, а точнее, совсем ничего не понял. Откуда у вас берется датавремя и откуда известно, какой там часовой пояс?

Comment: Данное поле находится в DTO,  DTO заполняется необходимыми  данными из БД и в формате json отправляется на фронт, ранее все конвертировалось перед отправкой в UTC, но сейчас понадобилось отправлять данные у учетом хранящейся timezone, но используемый pattern для этого не подходит, его необходимо скорректировать так чтобы он работал и для +03:00 и для +11:00

Comment: А что это за класс `DateTime`?  В Java Date/Time API есть `LocalDateTime`, и `ZonedDateTime`, до появления этого апи было в основном `java.util.Date` / `java.sql.Timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Если класс `DateTime` относится к библиотеке [org.joda](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), то потребуется сконфигурировать `ObjectMapper` для его сериализации с указанием часового пояса, зарегистрировав модуль `JodaModule`, и установив флаг `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID`:

```java
@Data
class Dto {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
    private final DateTime hiringDate;
}
```

```java
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID);
om.registerModule(new JodaModule());

Dto dto = new Dto(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Samara")));

System.out.println(om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(dto));
```

Вывод:

```
{
  "hiringDate" : "2022-01-11 21:39:54 +0400[Europe/Samara]"
}
```